# Refresh parsing code android

Tags: android, json, android-intent

I am using the JSON parser to parse some pages but I would like to recall the parsing function every 30 seconds. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the method to call a method every 30 seconds is by using postDelay of Handler see below code.

```
  Handler handler;
    handler=new Handler();
    handler.removeCallbacks(run);
    handler.post(run);

 Runnable run=new Runnable()
 {
    public void run()
    {
        parsing();
        handler.postDelayed(run,30000);
    }
 };
```

Another approach is by using "[AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)"

Comment: You mean AlarmManager?Yes it is a class

Answer (score 0):

That is a weird need, only parsing when necessary would probably be a lot better.
Anyway, you should have a look at [Timers](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and [background services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) but be sure of what you are doing : if you create a background service that make a network call twice every minute, if that call is costly, you could cost a lot of data and/or battery to your users which is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a timer.

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
```

After that you can call use the schedule method to call your json parser method.

```
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() 
{
public void run() {
timerMethod();
}
}, 0, 1000);


private void timerMethod()
{
this.runOnUiThread(doSomething);
}


private Runnable doSomething = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
// Your code for doing something
}
```